# my video chat app (react.js + node.js) interface not showing video output while users are connected throgh different wifi connection

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I was trying to build an react.js app with node.js integrated in backend video chatting app . after deploying(frontend in Netlify and backend in Heroku) the app I tested the app connecting both same and different wifi . My app is working fine when both the devices are connected in same wifi but it   don't show any video output while connected in different wifi/data connection .I am sharing all the code , please ask me anything if you want to know anything

code used is backend :

```
const app = require("express")();


const server = require("http").createServer(app);



const cors = require("cors");


 const io = require("socket.io")(server, {

cors: {

    origin: "*",

    methods: [ "GET", "POST" ]

}
```

});

```
app.use(cors());

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

res.send('Running the chat server');
```

});

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {

socket.emit("me", socket.id);


socket.on("disconnect", () => {

    socket.broadcast.emit("callEnded")

});

socket.on("callUser", ({ userToCall, signalData, from, name }) => {

    io.to(userToCall).emit("callUser", { signal: signalData, from, name });

});

socket.on("answerCall", (data) => {

    io.to(data.to).emit("callAccepted", data.signal)

});
```

});

```
server.listen(PORT, () => {

console.log(`Server is running for chat app on port ${PORT}`)
```

});

code used in frontend(all the Js code was written in one single page) :

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

import Peer from 'simple-peer';


const SocketContext = createContext();


const socket = io('https://peaceful-caverns-09507.herokuapp.com/');


const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {

const [callAccepted, setCallAccepted] = useState(false);

const [callEnded, setCallEnded] = useState(false);



const [stream, setStream] = useState();


const [name, setName] = useState('');


const [call, setCall] = useState({});


const [me, setMe] = useState('');



const myVideo = useRef();


const userVideo = useRef();


const connectionRef = useRef();



useEffect(() => {

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })

    .then((currentStream) => {

      setStream(currentStream);


      myVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;

  });

  socket.on('me', (id) => setMe(id));


  socket.on('callUser', ({ from, name: callerName, signal }) => {

  setCall({ isReceivingCall: true, from, name: callerName, signal });

 });
```

}, []);

```
 const answerCall = () => {

 setCallAccepted(true);

 const peer = new Peer({ initiator: false, trickle: false, stream });

 peer.on('signal', (data) => {

  socket.emit('answerCall', { signal: data, to: call.from });

});

peer.on('stream', (currentStream) => {

  userVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;

});

peer.signal(call.signal);

connectionRef.current = peer;
```

};

const callUser = (id) => {

```
const peer = new Peer({ initiator: true, trickle: false, stream });

peer.on('signal', (data) => {

  socket.emit('callUser', { userToCall: id, signalData: data, from: me, name });

});

peer.on('stream', (currentStream) => {


  userVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;

});

socket.on('callAccepted', (signal) => {

  setCallAccepted(true);

  peer.signal(signal);

});

connectionRef.current = peer;
```

};

const leaveCall = () => {

```
setCallEnded(true);

connectionRef.current.destroy();

window.location.reload();
```

};

return (

```
<SocketContext.Provider value={{
```

call,callAccepted,myVideo,userVideo,stream,name,setName,callEnded,me,callUser,leaveCall,answerCall}}>
{children}

```
</SocketContext.Provider>
```

);
};

```
export { ContextProvider, SocketContext };
```